# 404 Error shown when getting variable value from .htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting this error

The requested URL /redirect-sdksm was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

my .htaccess code is

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^redirect-(.*) test2.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

my test2.php code is

```
  <?php
  $vl=$_GET['id'];
  echo $vl;
  ?>
```

Comment: Is rewrite module/htaccess enabled?

Comment: I think yes. I am on shared hosting and i have two more domains on same hosting which are using similar code which is working

Comment: Try using an absolute rewrite path **/test2.php?id=$1**

Comment: .I tried. but didn't work

Comment: Then 404 error means you are not allowed to rewrite **/redirect-foo** to **/test2.php** . Do you have any other rules in this htaccess?

Comment: No. This is the only code

Comment: To test the htaccess : add the following example code 

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?demo/?$ /test2.php?id=working [NC,L]` 

And the go to http://yoursite.com/demo you will be internally redirected to /test.php if the htaccess is working.

Comment: Yes. I think my htaccess is not working

Comment: The `AllowOverride` config is not set properly.